# How to determine out what Wi-Fi channel is used from the command line?

Tags: wifi, command-line

If I hold <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> and click the Airport icon at the top, I get a bunch of extra data about the access point I'm connected to.

Most interestingly for me right now is the Wi-Fi channel. `ifconfig` doesn't seem to include it.

How can I get this same info from the command line?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/323548/how-to-determine-the-wifi-channel-from-mac-command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType` from the command line - that will probably give you all the info you need. It's not terribly speedy though (just checked it with Lion, looks like the format has changed but it's still all there).

Answer (score 6):

There is a command line `airport` that is buried deep in the system framework that seems to be safe to call from the terminal. You can make a quick shell alias if you prefer short commands.

From [macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101205025505240)

1. Create an alias in your ~/.profile for the Airport Utility:
   (this should all be on the same line with **NO SPACE** between `airport='...`, but it won't fit on one here!)
   `> alias`
    `airport=`
   `'/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/`
   `airport'`
2. Then you can run this command to find out more info:
    `> airport en1 scan`

Comment: You should not be dropping things into /usr or /usr/bin.  Create your own ~/bin directory, or create /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Changed it.  That is the way I would have done it anyway.

Comment: It gets my vote.

Comment: Thanks but `scan` doesn't show which network I'm connected to. It shows all available networks and their strengths, but I'm not necessarily on the strongest.

Comment: You might try 'airport -I'

Answer (score 2):

In Mountain Lion try

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I
```

To see other options use

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -help
```